# For any collection $\mathfrak{X}:=\{X_i:i\in I\}$ if $J\subseteq I$ then $\Pi_{j\in J}X_j$ is embeddable in $\Pi_{i\in I}X_i$

Tags: general-topology

> **Statement**
>
> For any collection $\mathfrak{X}:=\{X_i:i\in I\}$ if $J\subseteq I$ then $X_J:=\Pi_{j\in J}X_j$ is embeddable in $X_I:=\Pi_{i\in I}X_i$

To prove the statement I tried to proceed as follows.

> For a fixed $\xi\in X_I$ we define the function $f:X_J\rightarrow X_I$ through the condiction
> $$
> [f(x)](i):=\begin{cases}x(i),\,\,\,\text{if}\,\,\,i\in J\\\xi(i),\,\,\,\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
> $$
> for any $x\in X_J$. So we observe that if $f(x)=f(y)$ for any $x,y\in X_J$ then $x(j)=[f(x)](j)=[f(y)](j)=y(j)$ for any $j\in J$ and so $x=y$ thus $f$ is injective. Then we observe that $(\pi_i\circ f)$ is equal or to $\pi_i$ if $i\in J$ or to a constant function $\xi_i$ each of which is continuous so that by universal mapping theorem for products we conclude that $f$ is continuous too.

Now unfortunately I can't prove that the function $f^{-1}$ is continuous that is the function $f$ is open so I ask to do it. Then I ask to prove that $f[X_J]=\Pi_{i\in I}Y_i$ where $Y_i=X_i$ if $i\in J$ and otherwise $Y_i=\{\xi_i\}$. Finally I ask if using the preceding result is possible to prove that if $X_I:=\Bbb R^{i-1}\times\Bbb R\times\Bbb R^{n-i}$ and $X_J:=\Bbb R^{i-1}\times\Bbb R^{n-i}$ then for any open $U$ there exist an open set $U'$ in $\Bbb R^{i-1}$ and an open set $U''$ in $\Bbb R^{n-i}$ such that $U\cap f[X_J]=U'\times\{\xi_i\}\times U''$. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: Just prove that $f$ is open. What is a basic open set in $X_J$, and what would its image be? Is it relatively open in the subspace that is the range of $f$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila So I know that the set $\mathcal{S}:=\{\pi_j^{-1}[U_j]:j\in J\}$ is a subbase of $X_J$ so that the collection of its finite intersection is a base for $X_j$.

Comment: So I have to prove that $f\big[\bigcap_{i=1}^n\pi_j[U_j]\big]$ is open in $f[X_j]$ for any $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: But how to prove this?

Comment: If $f$ is 1-1 then $f[\bigcap_i A_i]= \bigcap_i f[A_i]$.. (recall from elementary set theory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clear that $f[X_J] = \prod_{i \in I} Y_j$ where $Y_j$ is as you specified:
Let $y \in f(x)$ for $x \in X_J$ so that $y(i)=f(x)(i)=\xi(i)$ for $i \in I\setminus J$ is by definition, and so the left to right inclusion is clear. And if $y \in \prod_{i \in I} Y_j$, $\pi'_I(y)$ is the (unique) preimage of $y$ under $f$.

A basic open set in $X_J$ is of the form $U=\bigcap_{j \in F} \pi_j^{-1}[O_j]$ where $F \subseteq J$ is finite and $O_j \subseteq X_j$ is open for all $j \in F$.
Then $f[U]= f[\bigcap_{j \in F} \pi_j^{-1}[O_j]]= \bigcap_{j \in F} f[\pi_j^{-1}[O_j]]$ (as $f$ is 1-1 it preserves intersections in forward images) and $f[\pi_j^{-1}[O_j]] = {\pi'_j}^{-1}[O_j] \cap f[X_I]$, where $\pi'_j$ are the projections on $X_I$. So that intersection is also relatively open, showing that $f: X_I \to f[X_I]$ is open.

Comment: Okay, finally using the results that $\Bbb R^{i-1}\times\{\xi_i\}\times\Bbb R^{n-i}$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^{i-1}\times\Bbb R^{n-i}$ is it possible to prove that $U\cap X_i=U'\times\{\xi\}\times U''$ as I stated?

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately I don't be able to prove this. So could you help me, please?

Comment: I discovered the above embedding just to prove this.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro it’s false as stated because e.g. not every open set in the plane is a product of two open sets in the axes.

Comment: I think I made a mistake. Actually I mean that if $X_I:=\Bbb R^{i-1}\times\Bbb{R}\times\Bbb R^{n-i}$ and $X_J:=\Bbb R^{i-1}\times\Bbb R^{n-i}$ then $U\cap f[X_J]=U'\times\{\xi_i\}\times U''$ where $U'$ and $U''$ are open respectively in $\Bbb R^{i-1}$ and in $\Bbb R^{n-i}$.

Comment: I claim this because if $X_I:=\Bbb R^{n-1}\times\Bbb R$ and $X_J:=\Bbb R^{n-1}$ then the function $f^{-1}$ argree with the projection $\tilde{\pi}$ $_{\Bbb R^{n-1}}$ of $f[X_J]=\Bbb R^{n-1}\times\{\xi\}$ to $\Bbb R^{n-1}\times\{\xi\}$ and so if $U_\xi:=\pi_{\Bbb R^{n-1}}\big[U\cap f[X_j]\big]$ then $U\cap f[X_J]=\big(\pi_{\Bbb R^{n-1}}\big)^{-1}[U_\xi]=U_\xi\times\{\xi\}$, is this false?

Comment: And this last thing is stated by Munkres.

Comment: So what can you say about?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro the last case where $X_I = \Bbb R^{n-1}$, $X_J= \Bbb R^n$, $f[X_I]= \Bbb R^{n-1} \times \{\xi\}$ then for every open $U \subset \Bbb R^n$ we have that $U':=\pi_J[U]$ is open in $\Bbb R^{n-1}$ and $U' \times \{\xi\} = U \cap f[X_I]$. That works fine.